# how to solve the slider blank space problem while scrolling the image?

Tags: html, css, laravel, slider

I am using a carousel slider. There is a blank space while scrolling from one image to the next one.

How do I solve the problem of blank space?

Here is my blade code for slider:

```html
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
      @foreach ($image_info as $item)
      @if ($item->key == 'banner1' )
          <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block w-100"
         src="{{ asset('storage/'.$item->image_url) }} " alt="alternative">
          </div>
      @endif
    @endforeach
    @foreach ($image_info as $item)
    @if ($item->key == 'banner2' )
    <div class="carousel-item">
       <img class="d-block w-100" 
        src="{{ asset('storage/'.$item->image_url) }} " alt="alternative">
    </div>
    @endif
    @endforeach
    @foreach ($image_info as $item)
    @if ($item->key == 'banner3' )
    <div class="carousel-item">
       <img class="d-block w-100" 
       src="{{ asset('storage/'.$item->image_url) }} " alt="alternative">
    </div>
    @endif
    @endforeach
    
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" 
    role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" 
      role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The way your code is currently, if I understand you are looping through the same array/collection 3 times. Why so? Why not just use one loop with only an if statement for the `active` class rather than the entire block?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you only need a single `foreach` loop and you can check for the condition of `'banner1' and apply the active class within the loop.

```php
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    @foreach ($image_info as $item)  
      <div class="carousel-item @if($item->key == 'banner1') active @endif">
        <img class="d-block w-100"
         src="{{ asset('storage/'.$item->image_url) }}" alt="alternative">
      </div>
    @endforeach
    
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" 
    role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" 
      role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```